# text unresponsive to css

Tags: html, css, colors, navbar

I'm trying to change the color f my navbar buttons with the "white" class, but for some reason they are unresponsive to my css. The first html snippet is the unresponsive ones, and the second is where it worked fine.

```css
.white {
 color: #aaaeb5;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li class="white"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
           <li class="white"><a href="#Who We Are">Who We Are</a></li>
           <li class="white"><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>

           </ul>
              
              
              <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <footer class="footer">
   <h3 class="white col-sm-12 text-center">Palacios Beauty Salon</h3>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/290+Broadway,+Brooklyn,+NY+11211/@40.7083862,-73.9605364,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c25be0961830a5:0xc6f496d3baa1bd27!8m2!3d40.7083862!4d-73.9583477"><h5 class="white col-sm-12 text-center"><i class="fa fa-building white padding" aria-hidden="true"></i>290 Broadway, Brooklyn, 11211</h5></a>
   <h5 class="white col-sm-12 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone white padding" aria-hidden="true"></i>(718) 123-4567</h5>
   <h5 class="white col-sm-12 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o white padding" aria-hidden="true"></i>Palaciossalon@gmail.com</h5>
   
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is the `<a>` tags. You have three options to do it:

> 1. adding class white to the `<a>` tags, not the parent `<li>` tags:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a class="white" href="#About">About</a></li>
<li><a class="white" href="#Who We Are">Who We Are</a></li>
<li><a class="white" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

> 2. adding `!important` to your CSS:

```
.white {
color: #aaaeb5 !important;
}
```

> 3. adding `.white a` to your CSS:

```
.white, .white a {
color: #aaaeb5;
}
```

I recommend option #1.

Answer (score 1):

you need to target the links `a` to override the default color set by the browser:

```css
.white a {
  color: #aaaeb5;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="white"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li class="white"><a href="#Who We Are">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li class="white"><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>

  </ul>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <footer class="footer">
        <h3 class="white col-sm-12 text-center">Palacios Beauty Salon</h3>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/290+Broadway,+Brooklyn,+NY+11211/@40.7083862,-73.9605364,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c25be0961830a5:0xc6f496d3baa1bd27!8m2!3d40.7083862!4d-73.9583477">
          <h5 class="white col-sm-12 text-center"><i class="fa fa-building white padding" aria-hidden="true"></i>290 Broadway, Brooklyn, 11211</h5>
        </a>
        <h5 class="white col-sm-12 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone white padding" aria-hidden="true"></i>(718) 123-4567</h5>
        <h5 class="white col-sm-12 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o white padding" aria-hidden="true"></i>Palaciossalon@gmail.com</h5>

    </div>
  </div>
```